# Python program reacting to an event

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm programming in Python a "Robot Controller" that controls V-Rep simulated Robot. My Robot has a Proximity Sensor that can be True (if it detects something in front of him) or False (if it's free ahead). I want that as soon as my Sensor changes from False to True, Python program will react, for example, calling a procedure.

The state of the Sensor is stored in a Boolean variable in Python but I would, of course, avoid a Busy Form of Waiting:

```
While True:
    if sensor_state:
       # Do Something
```

I want that during the normal flow of the program, as soon as the sensor_state changes, some statements has to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a while loop, you might go with something like this:

```
while False:  # You said that True indicates there's something ahead
    if object_ahead:
        sensor_state = True
```

Or you can just break out of the loop & forego the boolean variable all together:

```
while False:
    if object_ahead:
        break
```

If you can't use a while loop because you need your program to be doing other things during that time, then look into using the "threading" module to call a function as a separate thread.